# Representing classes of objects and type with number so they can be dismantled

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, contest-math, puzzle

I have a problem where I have several objects and several properties, I need a number which represent each of them so if I do an addition of those number I can dismantle those numbers.

for example lets say that I have 4 people , and 4 hats.
I can represent the people with numbers 0-3.
and I can represent the hats with numbers 10,20,30,40.
So if I'm getting the number 42, I know that I have person number three with hat number 4.

Now in this case I need the **minimum number value for each class** so it would still be separable.

Now my specific problem :
I have 6 persons , each one has 7 different classes (hat/shirt/etc') , and each class has 4 types (for example 4 possible hats, 4 possible shirt,etc').
in a case that a person doesn't has a shirt the value of shirt is 0(same case for no hat and etc..)

Please let me know if there is any need for any further explanation.

Thanks

Comment: Is "no hat" one of the four types?

Comment: @R.Burton No , Its another one(represented by 0)

Comment: Does it need to be a decimal (base-10) number, or can you use a different radix as long as the values are mimized?

Comment: @R.Burton it has to be a decimal integer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caution: I have limited experience with radix-conversion so there may be one or more errors here. However, the principle (enumerating all possible combinations) is sound.

For each integer $0\le n< 6\cdot5^7$ let $n_0,\ldots, n_7$ be the unique sequence such that...

$$n=\sum_{i=0}^7n_{i}\cdot5^{7-i}\qquad:\qquad 0\le n_0<6,\quad 0\le n_1,\ldots, n_7<5$$

Use $n_0$ to indicate the person, and $n_1,\ldots,n_7$ to indicate each of the seven properties. If I've done everything correctly (and I'm not sure that I have), then the string of digits $n_0n_1\cdots n_7$ will give person, hat, shirt, etc.

This is basically representing each combination as an eight-digit mixed-radix number, then converting that into decimal. In principal the highest such number should equal the total number of possible combinations, minus one ($``54444444"=6\cdot5^7-1$). This is necessarily the smallest maximum value that can be used.